# Send Json to kafka Topic

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm trying to send Json data into kafka topics:
I have this Scala code:

```
  def sendMessage(sender_id: String, receiver_id: String, content: String) = {
    val newMessage = new Producer(brokers = KAFKA_BROKER, key = "1", topic = "topic_2", message = {
      sender_id + receiver_id + content
    })
    newMessage.sendMessages()

  }
```

I want to send the sender_id, receiver_id & content as Json data to my topic but that doesn't seem to work.
This is my producer code

```
class Producer(topic: String, key: String, brokers: String, message: String) {

  val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](configuration)

  private def configuration: Properties = {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers)
    props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all")
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, classOf[StringSerializer].getCanonicalName)
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, classOf[StringSerializer].getCanonicalName)
    props
  }

  def sendMessages(): Unit = {
    val record = new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, key, message)
    producer.send(record)
    producer.close()
  }
```

I want to save the content as Json to custom retreive it later from my consumer.

Comment: as an aside - probably not a good idea to create a new producer for each message

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz what do you suggest then ?

Comment: more the parameters to the send  so you can reuse the class , add a close method etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is not JSON, it is a code block; most importantly, JSON has key-value pairs.

```
   message = {
      sender_id + receiver_id + content
    }
```

You would need to add an external library such as [`json4s`](https://json4s.org/) to create a JSON string and/or case-class object for serialization.

```scala
val json = ("sender_id" -> sender_id, ...)
producer.send(new ProducerRecord(topic, compact(render(json)))
```

Comment: This seems to be a good article using Circe JSON, which has Kafka serializers provided. https://itnext.io/a-cqrs-approach-with-kafka-streams-and-scala-49bfa78e4295

Comment: yeah I know that wasn't JSON format, I just didn't know how to add it to kafka, I mean, what changes should I make, like for example, should I change something in here KafkaProducer[String, String] or anywhere else ?

Comment: Kafka stores bytes. Theres nothing to add. Your question is purely Scala. How do you create a JSON string **in Scala**??

Comment: BEWARE: [json4s is vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks!](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)